# What the difference between full research paper and WIP?

Tags: publications, peer-review, conference

Recently, I have got a notification from a conference saying that my research paper has been accepted to be published in LNCS proceedings as Work-in-progress paper. Therefore, I am asking if there any differences between WIP or full research paper when it becomes to be public and available online.

Will the reader differentiate whether the paper is a full research paper or work-in-progress paper? also, will the paper be citable by others(has ODI or ISBN)?

Comment: Haven you asked LNCS what they mean by this term?

Comment: @einpoklum as their website state:  Each paper will undergo a thorough process of peer reviews by the Program Committee. Reviewing is single-blind: author name(s) should appear. All papers accepted in any of the conference tracks will be included in the conference proceedings, which will be published by Springer-Verlag in the LNCS series. Proceedings will be made available at the conference. Submission implies that at least one author will register and attend the conference if the paper is accepted.

Comment: @einpoklum "LNCS" means Springer's _Lecture Notes in Computer Science_ book series, which includes several conference proceedings. Nobody at Springer can answer OP's first question. The right people to ask are other people familiar with the research community that publishes at the conference—for example, OP's advisor.

Comment: Not knowing the minds of the reviewers I can only assume that you left enough questions unanswered, at least in their minds, that they didn't consider it finished. They might be right or wrong, but I'd look to the paper itself to try and see why they might come to such a conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

When you later publish the full research paper, you can (should!) cite the conference proceedings as that work will have been incorporated into your research paper. Many researchers that find your conference paper will look for some follow-up to the conference paper, particularly if you make a note in the paper that it is a work in progress.

With online publishing there are often citation connections made in both directions, so as well as the reference list showing which papers are cited in that paper, there is often a reverse-reference list showing which papers cite that paper. This makes things considerably easier, although I have no information about how comprehensive such reverse referencing is, and it may vary by field.